# Move file into apropriate directory based upon first letter of second word, followed by the first two letters of the second word with Python

Tags: python, operating-systems, sorting, scripting

EDIT: Apparently the below question is too specific. Let me rephrase:

I'm looking for a way to fit a letter into a list of specified ranges such that, if given the letter S and the ranges A-F, G-M, N-T, U-Z, it would select the third range.

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

So let's say I have a file: John_Smith.pdf

And I have a directory hierarchy like so:

```
A/
B/
C/
D/
...
Z/
```

And inside each of those directories there are subdirectories that further breaks files down by the first two letters rather than the first (the breakdowns are not the same in every folder). In the S/ directory, the subdirectories could look like this:

```
SA-SF/
SG-SM/
SN-ST/
SU-SZ/
```

How can I, using Python, put John_Smith.pdf into the appropriate directory (`S/SG-SM/`)? It would be preferable for this to be as OS agnostic as possible (e.g. using `os.path.join` instead of hard coding '/' or '\'. )

Thanks!

Comment: recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)** "...If your question on Programmers.SE is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: ...are you by chance [blocked at Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260) for asking questions like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a specific implementation issue, but appears to be a 'write this code for me problem' without identifying the problem with the existing code.

Comment: It isn't a homework problem. This is an actual problem I need to solve. I'm new to Python and am teaching myself. And no, I'm not blocked. I'm not asking anyone to write code for me. Even if you gave me a suggestion of which functions to look into, that'd be very helpful.

Really what I'm asking is for a python module/function that can "fit" a letter into the appropriate range. Obviously this would be fairly trivial with numbers but I'm not sure about letters. If you want me to make the question less specific and resubmit, I'm happy to.

Comment: @chad it is still asking people to write your code for you. You should ask this at Stack Overflow. However, in its current state it would either be closed or receive little to no attention. You could improve it by trying this on your own and showing what you tried: SO is about "this code does not work, how do I fix it?" I do not see any broken code in your question.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't know how to start. I apoligize for posting in the wrong place. It doesn't matter now I guess. I posted somewhere else and got the answer. Sorry for inconveniencing all of you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3e59qe/how_to_fit_a_letter_into_a_range/ctbmzhf). Python actually has this functionality built in. For example

'A' < 'F' # Returns true because A comes before F

Thus one can use the function

```
def is_in_range(range, letter):
    return range[:2] <= letter <=range[3:5]


is_in_range('SA-SF','SM')
False

is_in_range('SG-SM','SM')
True
```

Note: Case will screw this up so `.upper()` will be needed